# reading public data insights from page fan about facebook

Tags: facebook-insights

I have noticed that for obtaining the insight information, Facebook provides a particular graph api but unfortunately I can only access at page_fans_country and page_storytellers data.

However i've seen that if i go in a general fan page, there is a "likes" section (in the "About" page) where it is created a graph about the trend of "talking_about_this" number and trend of "like" number.

this two graph are "canvas" object and if I move the mouse over them, it is displayed some information which are impossible to obtain by graph api. I've tried to find a method to take this information by analysing javascript code.

Once thing I'v understood
is that there is a "mouseover" event that [active a code at 118 line](https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yA/r/gsJq34yNAno.js)
javascript page and this code show a div element in html page with classname "graphTooltip". however i dont able to get a text information in this div element. Does anyone know how obtain that text?